# two labels changes positions automitic when their width change by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vb.net

I have label in anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="Anchor" class="class1"><span><asp:label ID="label1"   runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Smaller" Text=text1" >
```

and a `label2` to contain a user name. What I want is when `label2` adjusts its width according to user name then `label1` auto adjusts its position according to `label1`. Here I have a problem when the username is something like "tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" - after this `label1` aligns, but when the username is smaller like "ttttt" then a lot of space is shown between the labels.

```
 .class1 
    {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 65px;
    right: 43.3%;
    /*left: 30.6%;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

     }

     body.reversed .class1 {
        left: 8px;
        right: auto;
    }
    .fixed-title-bar > .class1 {
        position: fixed;
    }
    .class1 > span {
        padding: 0 8px 0 30px;
        background: url(../img/inout5.png) no-repeat 7px center;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 27px;
        line-height: 27px;
    }

    .class1 > span {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #020203;
        color: white;
        -webkit-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
        -moz-text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
        background-color: #454545;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width:56px;

    }
```

Comment: Could you try and provide code examples that only show the problem? Removing unneeded code will make it easier for people to help.
Your example code is incomplete (no closing tags) and please show where label2 is in relation to label1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue reslove by some CSS setting and ul li tags